# Use of Makefile in RStudio

Tags: r, makefile, gnu-make, rstudio, rstudio-server

Why RStudio does not **display** structure of `Makefile`, especially specific *targets*, in RStudio's `Build` tab? I would expect it to display them and allow one to **build** those specific targets. Is this feature lacking in RStudio and RStudio Server or it's there and I just need to know where to enable it?

Comment: Not implemented yet. You might want to request it at https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us

Comment: @hadley: I'd appreciate if you could take a look at my open Qs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Submitted as feature request to RStudio Team: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200956606-Feature-request-Implement-Makefiles-targets-processing.